# C++ GNU designated structure initialization not recognized in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, eclipse-cdt

The CDT parser reports a syntax error for the structure initialization:

```
typedef struct MyStruct
{
    int a;
    float b;
};

int main( void )
{
    // GNU C extension format
    MyStruct s = {a : 1, b : 2};
    // C99 standard format
//    MyStruct s = {.a = 1, .b = 2};

    return 0;
}
```

While [GCC lists the `:` form as obsolete](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits), it would seem that it has not been deprecated nor removed.  In C99 I would certainly use the standard `.<name> =` form but for C++, the `:` is the only option that I am aware of for designated initialization.

I have tried setting my toolchain to both MinGW and Cross GCC, but neither seem to work.

How can I get Eclipse to recognize this syntax?  It's not a big deal for one line but it carries through to every other instance of the variable since Eclipse does not realize it is declared.

Comment: To be clear, your goal is for your IDE's tools (like syntax highlighting) to understand this syntax?

Comment: The CDT parser is unrelated to the toolchain. It recognizes a number of GCC extensions, put probably not the ones marked obsolete.

Comment: Yes, I am hoping someone is aware of a setting I may have wrong that would trigger Eclipse to recognize this.  I figured that perhaps the toolchain would do this as it wouldn't make much sense to recognize GNU extensions when using a non-GNU compiler.

Answer (score 2):

The `.` form is only available in C99 and not in any flavor of C++. In C++ your only standards-compliant options are ordered initialization or constructors.

You *can* use chaining with appropriate reference returning methods to create a similar interface (here a and b are methods rather than variables):

```
MyStruct s;
s.a(1).b(2);
```

Comment: In my case the structure definition is in another project which is pure C.  I don't really know the history but we are using a C++ test framework for our C code.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

I meet this problems too and i use below method to solve it.

```
MyStruct s = {
 1,
 2,
}
```

This requires programmer to ensure sequence of initialization.